# How to control music playback on the phone from WearOS watch

Tags: android, media-player, wear-os, mediabrowserservicecompat, mediabrowser

I want remote control phone music playback  from WearOS watch just for play/pause/next/previous as system app does.
I have google a lot, building a media browser client in WearOS app looks right to implement this.

```kotlin
        val comp = ComponentName("com.android.bluetooth",
           "com.android.bluetooth.avrcpcontroller.BluetoothMediaBrowserService")

        mMediaBrowser = MediaBrowserCompat(context,comp,mConnectionCallbacks,null)
        mMediaBrowser?.connect()
```

but connection always failed

```
 Unable to start service Intent { act=android.media.browse.MediaBrowserService cmp=com.android.bluetooth/.a2dpsink.mbs.A2dpMediaBrowserService } U=0: not found
```

I also tried  **avrcpcontroller.BluetoothMediaBrowserService**

```
Unable to start service Intent { act=android.media.browse.MediaBrowserService cmp=com.android.bluetooth/.avrcpcontroller.BluetoothMediaBrowserService } U=0: not found
```

It seems there is no way to connect the mediabrowser from WearOS watch.

Comment: It is not currently supported. If you want to implement this at the moment, you will need to use the DataLayer and connect to your own app on mobile. It won't work generically for other apps.

Comment: Thank you for answer. Yeah,  I hope it can work generically with any audio apps.